# Parsing multiple category groups from Fixed Length File

Tags: java, fixed-width, bean-io

I am using BeanIO to parse records from a fixed length. For now, it works great. Now I have a new input file which has 2 different record groups as below.

```
Title xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Dummy Line
Dummy Line

Col1  Col2  Col3
Val1  Val2  Val3

Title xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Dummy Line
Dummy Line
Dummy Line

Col  Col  Col Col
Val  Val  Val Val
```

both of the above sections can occur any time of time and not in any order.

How can I create benio mapping to read them?

Comment: please add the mapping xml file or the source code with annotations you have tried so far

Comment: I will create and share sample mapping file when I get home as I can't share it from my work environment.